# How do I remove a bookmark in Evince Document Viewer?

Tags: evince

I need to remove an old bookmark and replace it with a new one.

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

- Select the bookmark from a drop-down list inside the side pane, if you don't see side pane, press <kbd>F9</kbd>
- Select the unwanted bookmark in the side pane
- Click the Remove button at the bottom of the side pane
- OR right-click and remove it

The bookmark section inside the drop-down list of the side pane is shown below:

[image]

Comment: Same for Atril Document Viewer.